# Python, how to convert the [(a,b,c)(d,e,f)(g,h,k)] array to numpy [[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,k]]

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, arraylist, brackets

I am working on the problem of visualizing 3D point sets in realtime and I need to convert the point cloud to the specific format. For example, the original data I get is something like

```
[(-1.3604002, -1.0681801, 1.8390535) (-5.5378942, -4.362379 , 7.5151973)
 (-0.       , -0.       , 0.       ) ...
 ( 0.       ,  0.       , 0.       ) ( 0.       ,  0.       , 0.       )
 ( 0.       ,  0.       , 0.       )]
```

with the format of `(307200,)`.
I am looking for a fast way to convert this data to the format like `(307200,3)` numpy array without using the for loop to go through every point. Thanks.

Comment: Ignoring the syntax errors (no comma between elements), this looks like it is already in a shape of `(n,3)`, so `np.array(data)` should work. Or are you saying this is string data you need to convert to python numerical data?

Comment: Format or `shape`? What's the `dtype`.  dtype will give us an idea as to why it is displaying with () instead of [].

Comment: @AChampion, I think this is the print (`str`) display of a structured array.  The `no comma` is normal for numpy arrays.  And the `()` is a structured array indicator.